# CakePHP GmailOath Retrieve Contacts

Tags: cakephp, oauth, google-contacts-api

below link is GmailOauth that I used for CakePHP but nowadays whenever there is new project, the generated Client ID and Client Secret no longer work like before. Any part that I need to modify it?

https://code.google.com/p/rspsms/source/browse/trunk/system/plugins/GmailContacts/GmailOath.php?r=11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution,

Looks like the newly generated Client ID and Client Secret have already phased out for older version of API. The only way to make this works is by implementing Google Contact APIv3 and using OAuth2.

Hope this help the rest who having the same issues.